# Show that a given line is tangent to a whole family of curves

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Here is my question:

For each real parameter, consider the function defined as follows $$f_m=\sqrt{mx^2-2(m-1)x+m}.$$
Show that the line $y=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}(x+1)$ is tangent to each curve $C_m$, representing $f_m$ $(m\in\mathbb{R}$).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

solving the equation $$f_m=y$$ for $x$ we get $$x=1$$ and differentiating both functions with respect to $x$ and plugging $$x=1$$ in these derivatives we get the same value.